# Understanding htaccess and $_GETs

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, .htaccess

This is how my site is constructed...

articles.php contains the layout html to display all articles for a category.
articles.js  contains the control elements to obtain db query results and pass to articles.php page. Within the js script is a dataTable that is displayed on the articles.php page.
ajax_articles.php contains the query request and return json file results of the query. Within the json file are  links to the individual articles. The link is structured as a clean SEO URL (e.g., article/001/moby_dick).

This is how I understand htaccess to work.

When a user selects an article the URL (i.e., https://www.example.com/article/001/moby-dick) is passed through htaccess and with a RewriteRule ^article/([0-9]+)/([a-z_-]+) article.php?art_id=$1&art_name=$2 [NC,L] will display the SEO 'pretty' URL, BUT known to the system will be the URL containing the two parameters that can be used by a $_GET to obtain the two parameters. IS MY UNDERSTANDING OF THE PROCESS CORRECT?

I've noticed that with the htaccess I now have to use the full path name to load the support (.js) and graphic files. Further, I cannot obtain the variables via js $_GET.art_id and $_GET.art_name.

Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: That description is very roughly ok-ish, but not precise. A dynamic configuration file (".htaccess") cannot somehow decide what URL is shown in the browser. That configuration file operates on the server side, the URL is shown on the client side. Both, the requested and the rewritten URL are known on the server side, actually multiple rewritten request URLs.

Comment: And `$_GET` does not make any sense in javascript. `$_GET` is a superglobal variable _inside the php engine_ , that has _nothing_ to do with the javascript engine. One is server side, one client side, there is very little connection between them, only the http requests, not more.

Comment: The reason why all of your media files have to be accessed via the root folder or absolute URLs is because the browser sees the content in between the slashes as directories, even if they technically don't exist. Once you introduce the /article/001/moby-dick the browser looks for /article/001 as the current folder.

Comment: Thanks for your responses. I was able to get one of the modules to work, but am still having a problem with others. As for the $_GET in js note my comment at the end of my question. Don't remember where I found it but I have been using the following js $_GET code for a few years now.

var $_GET = {0:0};
document.location.search.replace(/\??(?:([^=]+)=([^&]*)&?)/g, function () { 'use strict';
 function decode(s) {
  return decodeURIComponent(s.split("+").join(" "));
 }
 $_GET[decode(arguments[1])] = decode(arguments[2]);
});

Again, thanks!

Comment: I am beginning to understand the issues. My problem now is that I cannot use localhost for testing given that ALL file references must use the full file path. This might be OK for the image files but the javascript, CSS, AJAX, plus others are all in subdirectories of the main site. How can I thus do testing if the full path is required?

Comment: Have you managed to get this working?

Comment: Yes and no. I implemented the SEO method in some of the modules and they work fine. I now need to find all of the internal dynamic references that generate links to the modules and change their structure. Ran into a problem yesterday working on the updates. I have a search module that allows a search of the interments (burials). The SEO URLs for the interments is 'memorial/12345/some-ones-name.' But with the search it needs to be 'memorial/type/what/name' where type is whether to use the full interment table or a subset, what is 'last-name' or 'first-name' and 'name' is the name to search for.

Comment: To further answer your question... I still haven't got my mind around .htaccess. To make the SEO URLs work I included this in .htaccess... <code>RewriteRule ^modName/([0-9]+)/([a-z_-]+) modName.php?this_id=$1&this_name=$2 [NC,L] </code>which to me doesn't make sense. To me is says take a SEO URL and turn it into a $_GET URL, but the SEO URL is what appears. What am I missing? I guess I'm just to old school.

Answer (score 0):

You can't access the `GET` variables with javascript in this configuration because they do not exist after the URL rewrite. The query parameters have been removed.

There are still ways you can extract these values from the URL with `window.location.href` and the `.split()` method in javascript.

```js
// var myurl = window.location.href; // this will get the string of your current URL. Used manual string in this example
var myurl = "https://www.example.com/article/001/moby-dick"; // manual URL for sake of an executable example

var spliturl = myurl.split("/"); // ["https:","","example.com","article","001","moby-dick"]

var articleid = spliturl[4]; // "001"
var articlename = spliturl[5]; // "moby-dick"

// see the variables in action
console.log("id: ", articleid);
console.log("name: ", articlename);
```